# Plotting amplitude for thousands of frames

Tags: python

I have a time line consisting of thousands of frames (10000 in average).

I have signals occuring during these frames that have amplitude and duration.
for example:

> 00 11 000 555 000 8888 00 111 0000 2222

(the spaces just to show the different signals)

I want to plot the amplitude information over all the frames as bars to see the distribution of the non zero signals and I want the width of these bars to be equal to the number of frames of the represented signal

### Example output for the previous input

[image]

I tried [this](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html), but I couldn't represent the duration of the signal by editing the width of the column.
Also, it takes around a minute to plot and the zooming is really slow because of the nig number of frames.

### This is my code:

```
def show_all_full_time_lines(signals, frames):
    signals_amplitudes = [0]*len(frames)
    times = [frame.time for frame in frames]

    for signal in signals:
        start_time_index = times.index(signal.start_time)
        signals_amplitudes[start_time_index] = signal.total_distance

    ind = np.arange(len(frames))
    width = 0.35

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    rects1 = ax.bar(ind, signals_amplitudes, width, color='r')
    ax.set_ylabel('Amplitude')
    ax.set_xticks(ind + width)
    ax.set_xticklabels(times)
    plt.show()
```

which results after a minute of rendering:

[image]

(No width for the columns that represents the duration of each signal) and it is very slow.

Thank you very much

Comment: instead of a constant width `width = 0.35` an array of the different widths should work

Comment: Yea tgat worked for me thanks :D